# MongoDB aggregation framework sort by length of array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

Given the following data set:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("510458b188ce1d16e616129b"), "codes" : [ "oxtbyr", "xstute" ], "name" : "Ciao Mambo", "permalink" : "ciaomambo", "visits" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("510458b188ce1d16e6161296"), "codes" : [ "zpngwh", "odszfy", "vbvlgr" ], "name" : "Anthony's at Spokane Falls", "permalink" : "anthonysatspokanefalls", "visits" : 0 }
```

How can I convert this python/pymongo sort into something that will work with the MongoDB aggregation framework? I'm sorting results based on the number of codes within the `codes` array.

```
z = [(x['name'], len(x['codes'])) for x in restaurants]
sorted_by_second = sorted(z, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
for x in sorted_by_second:
    print x[0], x[1]
```

This *works* in python, I just want to know how to accomplish the same goal on the MongoDB query end of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> db.z.aggregate({ $unwind:'$codes'}, 
                 { $group : {_id:'$_id', count:{$sum:1}}}, 
                 { $sort :{ count: 1}})
```

Comment: That at least gives me a start. I'd like to have the full results shown, but at least I'm in the right direction. Any clues about the performance of this vs. the application side?

Comment: this might get closer:
    
    db.z.aggregate({ $unwind:'$codes'}, { $group : {_id:{name:'$name', permalink:'$permalink'}, count:{$sum:1}}}, {$sort:{count:-1}})

Performance? You'll have to test, but chances are your MongoDB server is IO-bound rather than CPU-bound, so spending some CPU doing the aggregation there, instead of filling the wire with documents for processing in Python, is probably a win.